# How to find the Fibonacci Sequence with C++?

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve [Problem 2](https://projecteuler.net/problem=2) on Project Euler. The problem is:

"Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:

1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...

By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms."

I am trying to solve this in C++.

Here is my code so far

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //ANSWER = 4613732
    int max = 4000000;
    int n;
    int sum;

    for(n=0; n<=max;)
    {
        while(n%2 == 0)
        {
            n = (n-1)+(n-2);
        }
    }
    sum = n+=0;
    cout << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see I know the correct answer from searching for it to check my answer. This code I have just runs forever and never shows an answer. Can anyone give me hints on how to arrive to this answer and to help improve my C++ code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: forgot to increase n? for(n=0; n<=max;n++)

Comment: It still runs forever and never outputs an answer

Comment: second while has the issue, why need to do this while loop?

Comment: I do it to make sure that n is an even number. Should it be an If statement or something other than while?

Comment: I'm sorry.. My title for this question doesn't really reflect on what I'm asking. Could you please take a look at my explanation right above my code.

Comment: I don't think you quite understand what the assignment is asking for or what your code is doing... you should try to reread the assignment and make sure you understand what it's asking before continuing.

Comment: Try to write code that will generate the first 10 numbers in the Fibonacci sequence. You already know these numbers.

Comment: I'm  pretty sure that the assignment is asking to find all of Fibonacci sequence up to 4 million then find the sum of all the even numbers in the sequence up to 4 million

Comment: Right, the assignment wants to sum the even Fibonacci *numbers* up to 4 million. Does your code do that? Where do you think your code calculates a Fibonacci number?

Comment: Take a piece of paper and work out the first few values n takes. It starts with 0, -3, ...

Comment: @NikBougalis I believe my code calculates a Fibonacci number in the while loop. correct?

Comment: I could of swore that was the formula for finding Fibonacci. Do you happen to know the formula.

Comment: you have in the statement of your question

Comment: @Worm: The formula is quite easy to find in google, but you don't even need the formula to test that your proposed solution is wrong. Calculate the few say 5 fibonacci numbers and compare with the known solution.

Comment: The Fibonacci number n is defined as the sum of the two preceding *Fibonacci* numbers, with the special case that F(0) = 0 and F(1) = 1. Think about what your formulate calculates carefully... you're calculating the sum of two consecutive numbers, ad infinitum.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an approach you should not follow.  (Note: this post is a joke, but I'm serious about not following this approach.  Attempting to understand this approach at your level of C++ understanding is also ill advised.)

```
#include <iostream>

struct Fib
{
  template<int n, int first=1, int second=1> struct Eval { enum {value = Eval<n-1, first, second>::value + Eval<n-2, first, second>::value}; };
  template<int first, int second> struct Eval<1, first, second> { enum {value = second}; };
  template<int first, int second> struct Eval<0, first, second> { enum {value = first}; };

};
struct SpecificFib
{
  template<int n> struct Eval { enum{ value = Fib::template Eval<n, 1, 2>::value }; };
};

template<int... values> struct Sequence {};
template<typename Seq, int n> struct Append;
template<int... values, int n> struct Append<Sequence<values...>, n> { typedef Sequence<values...,n> type; };
template<typename Seq, int n> struct Prepend;
template<int... values, int n> struct Prepend<Sequence<values...>, n> { typedef Sequence<n, values...> type; };

template<typename Func,typename Seq,typename Test=void> struct Filter;

template<typename Func,int first, int... values>
struct Filter<Func,Sequence<first,values...>,typename std::enable_if< Func::template Eval<first>::value>::type>
{
  typedef typename Prepend<typename Filter<Func,Sequence<values...>>::type,first>::type type;
};

template<typename Func,int first, int... values>
struct Filter<Func,Sequence<first,values...>,typename std::enable_if< !Func::template Eval<first>::value>::type>
{
  typedef typename Filter<Func,Sequence<values...>>::type type;
};
template<typename Func> struct Filter<Func,Sequence<>> { typedef Sequence<> type; };

struct IsEven {
  template<int n> struct Eval { enum{ value = !(n%2) }; };
};

template<typename Func,typename Seq> struct Map;
template<typename Func,int first, int... values>
struct Map<Func, Sequence<first,values...>>
{
  typedef Sequence<values...> Tail;
  typedef typename Map<Func,Tail>::type TailMapped;
  enum { firstMapped = Func::template Eval<first>::value };

  typedef typename Prepend<TailMapped,firstMapped>::type type;
};
template<typename Func>
struct Map<Func,Sequence<>>
{
  typedef Sequence<> type;
};

template<int begin, int end>
struct generate_sequence
{
  template<int current, int... values>
  struct helper: helper<current-1, current-1, values...> {};
  template<int... values>
  struct helper<begin, values...>
  {
    typedef Sequence<values...> type;
  };
  typedef typename helper<end>::type type;
};
template<typename Seq> struct Sum;
template<int first, int... values> struct Sum<Sequence<first, values...>> { enum {value = first + Sum<Sequence<values...>>::value}; };
template<> struct Sum<Sequence<>> { enum {value = 0}; };

template<typename Seq1, typename Seq2=Sequence<>>
struct Reverse { typedef Seq2 type; };

template<int first, int... values, typename Seq2>
struct Reverse<Sequence<first,values...>, Seq2>:Reverse<Sequence<values...>, typename Prepend<Seq2,first>::type> {};

template<typename Seq, char sep=','> struct PrintHelper;
template<int first, int second, int... values, char sep> struct PrintHelper<Sequence<first,second,values...>, sep>:PrintHelper<Sequence<second,values...>, sep>
{
  PrintHelper() { std::cout << sep << first; }
};
template<int last, char sep> struct PrintHelper<Sequence<last>, sep>:PrintHelper<Sequence<>, sep>
{
  PrintHelper() { std::cout << last; }
};
template<char sep> struct PrintHelper<Sequence<>,sep> { PrintHelper() {} void Do() const {} };
template<typename Seq, char sep=','> struct Print: PrintHelper< typename Reverse<Seq>::type, sep >
{};

typedef typename generate_sequence<0, 10>::type ZeroTo9;
typedef typename Map<SpecificFib,ZeroTo9>::type First10Fibs;
typedef typename Filter<IsEven,First10Fibs>::type First10FibsThatAreEven;

template<typename Sequence>
void PrintSomeInfo( std::string const& name )
{
  std::cout << name << " {";
  Print<Sequence>();
  std::cout << "} sums to " << Sum<Sequence>::value << "\n";
}
int main()
{
  PrintSomeInfo<ZeroTo9>("Zero to 9");
  PrintSomeInfo<First10Fibs>("First 10 fibs");
  PrintSomeInfo<First10FibsThatAreEven>("First 10 fibs that are even");
}
```

I hope that helps.

What I am doing above is playing around with template programming.  I'm deducing the answer using the rather over powered C++ type system, such that if a compiler properly compiled `Sum<Sequence>::value`, it would be a single compile-time value.

Technically, this is an answer to your question written in C++.  As a bonus, it will have `O(1)` run time.  :)

...

More seriously.  You need to solve your problem *one step at a time*.

Write a program that outputs the first 10 elements of the sequence.  I would say "like the above", but you should do it in a way you understand.

Comment: @Yuushi : Probably about the same as the point of the OP asking the question in the first place. ;-]

Comment: It uses C++, it finds the Fibonacci sequence, and it even sums up a subsequence of even elements.  What isn't to love?  It admittedly does not answer the OP's full question, but how is the OP supposed to learn without doing a step?

Answer (score 2):

Let's analyze your code step by step and see where you're going wrong:

```
    //ANSWER = 4613732
    int max = 4000000;
    int n;
    int sum;

    for(n=0; n<=max;)
    {
```

Let's stop right here... what does this loop do? It loops starting from 0, until n is equal to 4000001. The problem description asks you to sum the even Fibonacci terms that do not exceed 4000000. So you are, essentially, treating `n` as a variable that stores a Fibonacci number. OK...

```
        while(n%2 == 0)
        {
```

Now what does this code do? It loops while `n` is even. Why would you want to do that?

```
            n = (n-1)+(n-2);
```

OK. So what does this calculate? It sorta, kinda looks like something that would calculate a Fibonacci number. But does it? Let's check! You start with `n = 0`. Notice that `0 % 2 == 0` so you would execute this code, which would set n to: (0 - 1) + (0 - 2) = 0 - 1 + 0 - 2 = -3. The loop would then exit, since -3 is not an even number.

But... wait, -3 is not a Fibonacci number!

Remember, a Fibonacci number, let's call it F(n), is defined with the following formula: F(n) = F(n - 1) + F(n - 2), with special cases for F(0) = 0 and F(1) = 1. In other words a Fibonacci number is the sum of the previous two Fibonacci numbers.

So now, does the expression you wrote calculate Fibonacci numbers?

By the way, at this point you should be able to see why this code just run and run and run and run... If not, remember what `n` is and check the `for` loop. What will happen?

I am going to give you the answer; it's probably a little too complicated, but if you take the time to step through it *ON PAPER* and work it like the computer would, following each step line by line, you will see how it works and gain a better understand of C and C++ and how to translate algorithms and mathematical concepts into code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{           
    // We store the last 2 Fibonacci numbers that we calculated in this 
    // small array to improve the performance of our routine and avoid
    // having to recalculate things all the time. We update it as we go
    // and initialize it with the values for fib(0) and fib(1)

    int max = 4000000, ans = 4613732, sum = 0, lfi = 0, lfn = 1;
    int lastfibs[2] = { 0, 1 }; 

    do  
    {
        // Calculate the next fibonacci number in the sequence
        lfn = lastfibs[0] + lastfibs[1];

        // And store it in our cache, updating the cache index
        lastfibs[lfi++] = lfn;

        if(lfi == 2) // "round and round you're turning me..."
            lfi = 0;                

        if((lfn & 1) == 0) // An even Fibonacci number! Add it to the sum
            sum += lfn;
    } while(lfn <= max);

    if(sum != ans)
        cout << "BOO! The sum is " << sum << " but it's supposed to be " << ans << "!" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Yay! The sum is " << sum << "! Thanks StackOverflow!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I hope that it helps *you* **think** about the problem and *come up with your own solution*.

Comment: Yes, it was painful to watch.

Comment: *only because I don't think you will be able to turn it in and claim that it was your code* That must be the worst reason ever to provide an answer

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas That's certainly true. But first of all, this doesn't actually seem to be a homework assignment per se (he referenced Project Euler, so I'm assuming he's tinkering away on his own) and secondly, even if it was: if someone is stupid enough to turn in code that they don't understand in the hopes of getting a grade instead of sitting and learning they're only hurting themselves in the long run.

Comment: @NikBougalis: It was just a smart remark about the comment. Whether it is homework or not does not matter at all, but the comment that the reason was that made me smile :)

Comment: Hey, at least it made you smile!

Answer (score 0):

```
bool Ctest::fibonacci(int *fibo, int length)
{   
int m = 2, n =1,d,q;
int flag;

if(fibo[0]==0 && fibo[1]==1 && fibo[3]==1)
    flag = 1;

for(int i =3; i<length; i++)
{
    if(fibo[i] == m)
    {
     flag = 1;
    }
    else 
    {
        flag = 0;
    }

    d = m;
    q = m+n;
    m=q;
    n=d;
}

if (flag == 0)
{
    return TRUE;
}
else
    return FALSE;
```

}

Comment: its a function to check whether give array of integers is a fibonacci sequence or not. u have sequence as 0,1,1,2,3,5... upto n number of length so for first three element we check logically and later elements we check inside loop.

Answer (score -2):

```
x = 1;
y = 1;
sum = 0;
a = 0;

while ( x < 4000 ) {
  if ( (x % 2) == 0 ){
    a = x + a;   
  }
print "x\n";
sum = x + y;
x = y;
y = sum;
}
print "\na\n";
```

boom

Comment: i dont think 4 million is 4 thousand.